# Inaccessible public member variable of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

As the title says, i can't access the public member variable of the base class from my main file.

> Entity.h:14:10: error: 'char Entity::character' is inaccessible

entity.h:

```
#include "Vector2.h"
#include <Windows.h>

class Entity {
public:
    Entity(char character, WORD color, Vector2<int> pos);

    Vector2<int> pos;
    Vector2<int> vel;

    char character;
    WORD color;
};
```

player.h:

```
#include "Entity.h"

class Player : Entity {
public:
    Player(int lives, char character, WORD color, Vector2<int> pos);

    int lives;
    int points;
};
```

Constructor call in main:

```
int main(){
    Player player(0, 'C', FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, playerSpawn);
    char c = player.character; // error here
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that the word [attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) should probably not be used to describe member variables.

Comment: I moved your code around to hopefully make it read a bit more clear. If you feel that I violated or destroyed something, do feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44301405/edit) it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default level of access for inheritance of a class is private, so Player is inheriting Entity privately.

Precede the class name with public if you want public access.

```
class Player : public Entity {
...
};
```

Comment: *"The default level of access for inheritance is private"* - When using the `class` keyword.